# Find Number(length) of items before condition and after condition in javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have a array in which number of items will be changing upon other conditions

my response

```
[
  id:2,
  ages:[{
    name:'alex',
    age_id:1,
  },
    name:'mike',
    age_id:2,
  },
  {
    name:'sike',
    age_id:2,
  },
  {
    name:'hike',
    age_id:3,
  },
  {
    name:'ben',
    age_id:3,
  }]
]
```

I am getting the above response and storing it into my agePeople array like this

```
axios.get('/people').then((res)=>{
  this.agePeople  = res.data
})
```

then i am looping over it to check the number of items length before certain condition and after as i want to remove them using pop and shift functions

```
for(var i=0; b < this.agePeople.length; i++) {
  for(var b=0; b < this.agePeople[i].ages.length; b++) {
    if(this.agePeople[i].id == this.agePeople[i].ages[b].age_id) {
      //So when condition meets it should pop the elements before it and after it but both number of items before the condition and after are different
    }
  }
}
```

I have tries storing their count and the pop and shift the array that many times but it doesn't gives desired results  as the number of unmatched items can be changed on every other response

Comment: Please accept an answer if this solved your problem. Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` makes iteration on arrays much easier.
You haven't mentioned on which array you want to execute `pop` and `shift`, so I have assumed on `ages` array:

```
         this.agePeople.forEach(item1 => {
            item1.ages.forEach((item2,index) => {
               if (item1.id !== item2.age_id) {
                   item1.ages.splice(index,1);
               }
             })
         })
```

Comment: you shouldn't edit an array while looping through it

Comment: @KevinPotgieter Why not? I have done that  alot!

Comment: It will only show the first record with age_id = 2 i want both of them

Comment: @MohammadFahadRao Then I did edit my answer. Please check this one.

Comment: @Qiimiia if you edit an array whilst looping through it you will find yourself looking for `index = 6` but now that you've removed an earlier index you are actually looking at `index = 7`, for example

Comment: Run this : `let data = [0,1,2,3,4,5];` `data.forEach(function (index, value) { data.shift(); console.log(index, value); })` Notice how the index and value is not matched anymore

Comment: @KevinPotgieter You were right about changing the next index! It was a mistake. but I guess changing the index that I'm already iterating on, won't make a problem. e.g. check my edited answer.

Comment: Its good practice make a new array and not alter the original one you are iterating through

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without looping through the array. You should also never add or remove to an array while looping through it, doing so changes the length of the array and can cause your indexes to reference the wrong value.

```js
const data = {
  "id": 2,
  "ages": [
    {
      "name": "alex",
      "age_id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "mike",
      "age_id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "sike",
      "age_id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "hike",
      "age_id": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "ben",
      "age_id": 3
    }
  ]
}

const id = data.id; // set id in variable
const has_matching_age_id = data.ages.filter(d => d.age_id === id); // find a mathing item in array, return an array

if (has_matching_age_id.length) // if there was an item in the array that matched the condition
    data.ages = has_matching_age_id[0] //replace data.ages

console.log(data)
// {
//   "id": 2,
//   "ages": 
//     {
//       "name": "mike",
//       "age_id": 2
//     }
// }



// or if you want all the matching age_id's

if (has_matching_age_id.length) // if there was an item in the array that matched the condition
    data.ages = has_matching_age_id //replace data.ages

console.log(data)
// {
//   "id": 2,
//   "ages": [
//     {
//       "name": "mike",
//       "age_id": 2
//     },
//     {
//       "name": "sike",
//       "age_id": 2
//     }
//   ]
// }
```

Comment: I want both records with age_id =2

Comment: See the second comment in my answer